# Is there a way to fetch data about Facebook ads performance automatically for non PMDs

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to fetch data about my company's ads performance on Facebook in order to load it into our data warehouse.
The only automatic way I found is with Facebook app but it seems Facebook only grant access to PMDs.
Can anyone refer me to a documentation about fetching ads performance data for company's "personal" use?

Comment: Do you have access to the ads api already?

Comment: No, this is my problem. I would like to gain access to ads api but we are not PMD cause we are only interested in our data.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question

Answer (score 0):

Ads API is opening to public so you can build your own reporting: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/access

For reporting you'll need the act_{id}/reportstats endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/guides/chapter-7-ad-report-stats